# Movieclips clashing with bitmap mask

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to reveal this movie clip image which is originally a bitmap but needs to be used as a bitmap for this purpose. for some reason it's not working ...
It's not throwing any errors... I need this image to be masked as the user presses on it... and later be compared with another bitmap to carry out a function. but for some reason as I mentioned before it's not working out. can somebody please help me?? this is the code for it...

```
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var mouseclick:Number=0;
var maskedbg_mc:maskedbg = new maskedbg ();
var masking:Sprite = new Sprite()               

addChild (maskedbg_mc);
maskedbg_mc.x = 18;
maskedbg_mc.y = 343;
var bitmapDataCopy:BitmapData = new BitmapData(742,165,true,0x00FFFFFF);
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapDataCopy);

bitmapDataCopy.draw(maskedbg_mc);

b.mask = masking;
var Testing:BitmapData = new BitmapData(maskedbg_mc.width, maskedbg_mc.height, true, 0x00000000);


addChild(masking);


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Pressing);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, Moving);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Lifting);


function Pressing(event:MouseEvent):void {
mouseclick = 1;
}


function Moving(event:MouseEvent):void {
if (mouseclick == 1) {
masking.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
masking.graphics.drawEllipse(mouseX, mouseY, 70, 60);
masking.graphics.endFill();
}
}


function Lifting(event:MouseEvent):void {
mouseclick = 0;
}

if ( bitmapDataCopy.compare(Testing) ==0 )
{
    trace ("Awesomness")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overlooking your code, I notice you are not adding "b" (the masked DisplayObject) to the display list, while you are adding "maskedbg_mc" which actually isn't being masked in your code. Do you have a reason for having these 2 display objects?

I would recommend you following actionscript coding conventions:

http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Coding%20Conventions/

Your code looks quite confusing when you have both variables and functions with initial letter in uppercase, they look like classes.